# dynamic modal not loading data

Tags: ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

I have a `Modal` that display data dynamically,but it's not working and I have same `Modal` in my project and it's working but this new one I created is not working...

> getting http://127.0.0.1:8000/hr/received/receiveReprt/3 404 (Not Found) error in the console

**Function:**

```
public function receiveReprt($id)
    {
        $reprt = shareReport::select('content')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
        return $reprt;
    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/receiveReprt/{id}','HrController@receiveReprt');
```

**AJAX:**

```
$('a.view').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = 'receiveReprt';

      $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
            //success data
            console.log(data);
          $("#previewdoc").html(data.content);
          $('#viewModal').modal({show:true}); 

        }); 

  });
```

**Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="width:60%;">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Preview</center></h4>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="previewdoc" style="padding: 40px;">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span class="fa fa-times-circle"></span> Close
        </button>
      </div>
         </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try changing this line `var url = 'receiveReprt';` to `var url = '/receiveReprt';` in your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in the model name

```
public function receiveReprt($id)
        {
            $reprt = shareReport::select('content')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
            return $reprt;
        }
```

to

```
   public function receiveReprt($id)
            {
                $reprt = ShareReport::select('content')->where('id','=',$id)->first();
                return $reprt;
            }
```

Comment: fixed it...the route was the problem,it could not located the route